# Не могу получить promise response

Tags: javascript, promise

Хочу понять, как решить данную проблему. Суть в том, чтобы проверять дни по порядку на выходной-рабочий, пока в массиве не будет 3 рабочих дня, и возвращать последний. Проект на Angularjs 1.5, возможно, нужно писать как-то по-другому, используя $q, но я в этом пока новичок, поэтому буду благодарна за подсказку оптимального решения. Заранее большое спасибо

```js
function  getFinePlanDateTo() {
  let from = new Date(), workingDates = []
  let lastDay;
  getResult(from, workingDates, lastDay).then((resp)=>{
    console.log("resp", resp) // здесь не та дата
  });
}
        
        
function getResult (from, workingDates, lastDay) {
  from = new Date(from.setDate(from.getDate() + 1));
  return isWorkingDay(from).then(function (result) {
    if (result && result.working) {
      workingDates.push(from);
      lastDay = workingDates[workingDates.length - 1];
    }
    if (workingDates.length < 3) {
      getResult(from, workingDates, lastDay);

    } else {
      console.log(lastDay) // здесь дата верная, ее надо вернуть
      return lastDay
    }
    return lastDay

  })

}

 function isWorkingDay(day) { //сервис, который возвращает объект типа {working:true/false}
   return service.workingDay(day).then(function (result) { 
    return result
  })

}
```

Comment: В каком месте не можете получить? насколько я вижу, вы возвращаете результат, а не промис в функции `isWorkingDay`, поэтому в then он и не доходит. Так должно заработать - `return service.workingDay(day);`, тогда результат попадет в then выше

Comment: не хватает `return`: `if (workingDates.length < 3) {
      return getResult(from, workingDates, lastDay);

    }` Тут запускается новый Promise, но нигде не отслеживается

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev спасибо вам большое, вы правы

Comment: @Grundy вам тоже спасибо, после ваших с Артемом поправок все работает верно

Comment: @ЕкатеринаИштырякова, так же посмотри ответ к дубликату, там похожая проблема

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить последний рабочий день по-идее надо переписать метод так

```
function getResult (day) {
    return isWorkingDay(day).then(function (result) {
        if (result && !result.working) {
            return new Date(day.setDate(day.getDate() - 1))
        } else {
            let newDay = new Date(day.setDate(day.getDate() + 1));
            return getResult(newDay);
        }
    }
}
```